# The Ajax in JQuery is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make two post requests to the back end, Flask. I successfully got the login request yesterday, because I can see the information printed in the browser console. But After adding the second click event, both are failed. 
And the "login" post and "search" post request failed differently, because for the first I can see "clicked" in the console, but for the second nothing.

I also used request.get_data() and request.get_json(), but got nothing. I have used an easier way to get post request from Flask, like request.form. However, I am still very confused what's wrong with the code.

Thank you for offering help!

Below is the .js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// login, for sending the email and password
$(function () {
    $("form#formLogin").on('click','button#buttonLogin', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('form#formLogin').serialize(),
            contentType: 'json; charset=UTF-8',
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.d);
                console.log("login info sent");
            },
            fail: function (response) {
                console.log(response.d);
                console.log("failed");
            }
        })
    });
})


// search, for executing sql
$(function () {
    $('form#formSearch').on('click', 'button#buttonSearch', function () {
        console.log('begin sending select');

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('form#formSelect').serialize(),
            contentType: 'json; charset=UTF-8',
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.d);
                console.log("search info sent");
            },
            fail: function (response) {
                console.log(response.d);
                console.log("failed");
            }
        })
    });
})
})
```

Below is .html, the login part

```
<form id="formLogin" class="formLogin" method="post">
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please Login</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="post" class="form-control" value="login"/>

<label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="userEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus/>

<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="userPwd" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>

<label for="buttonLogin" class="sr-only">Login:</label>
<button id="buttonLogin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="login">login</button>

</form>
```

Below is .html, the search part

```
<form id="formSearch" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="post" class="form-control" value="select"/>

<div class="input-group mb-3 mt-4">

    <label for="selectRecord" class="sr-only">SelectRecord:</label>
    <input type="text" id="selectRecord" name="selectRecord" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"  required autofocus/>

    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label for="buttonSearch" class="sr-only">Search:</label>
        <button id="buttonSearch" name="buttonSearch" class="btn btn-outline-secondary search" value="search">Search</button>
    </div>

</div>

<label for="checkBoxRegion" class="sr-only">Region:</label>
<input id="checkBoxRegion" name="checkBoxRegion" type="checkbox"> <span class="checkboxFontSize">Region</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<label for="checkBoxProductName" class="sr-only">ProductName:</label>
<input id="checkBoxProductName" name="checkBoxProductName" type="checkbox"> <span class="checkboxFontSize">Product Name</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<label for="checkBoxStoreName" class="sr-only">StoreName:</label>
<input id="checkBoxStoreName" name="checkBoxStoreName" type="checkbox"> 
<span class="checkboxFontSize">Store Name</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Need to prevent the form default submit. Your page is likely just reloading due to the form

Comment: `$(function () {` is redundant inside of `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: Your contentType doesn't match the format of data you are sending.

Comment: `$("form#formLogin")` Do not include the tag name in the selector if selecting something by id

Comment: Yes, the data types don't match. Thanks a lot!